MissingDummyValueError: Either<Failure, User>
import 'package:flutter_bloc_master/core/common/entities/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_master/core/error/failures.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_master/features/auth/domain/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_master/features/auth/domain/usecases/user_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:fpdart/fpdart.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import 'user_login_usecase_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateMocks([AuthRepository])
void main() {
  late MockAuthRepository mockAuthRepository;
  late UserLogin userLogin;

  setUp(() {
    mockAuthRepository = MockAuthRepository();
    userLogin = UserLogin(mockAuthRepository);
  });

  const tEmail = 'dinodtharinda2001@gmail.com';
  const tPassword = '12345678';
  const user = User(id: '', email: tEmail, name: 'dinod tharinda');

  test('User login', () async {
    //arrange
    when(mockAuthRepository.loginWithEmailPassword(
            email: tEmail, password: tPassword))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(user));

    final result = await userLogin(
      UserLoginParams(email: tEmail, password: tPassword),
    );

    result.fold((l) {
      expect(l, isA<Failure>());
    }, (r) {
      expect(r, isA<User>());
    });
  });
}

Flutter mockito unit test not working. I used clean architecture for this project with blocs. Database is supabase
not working unit test. below I mention console log. when I use mockail comes different error.
console log
MissingDummyValueError: Either<Failure, User>
This means Mockito was not smart enough to generate a dummy value of type
'Either<Failure, User>'. Please consider using either 'provideDummy' or 'provideDummyBuilder'
functions to give Mockito a proper dummy value.
Please note that due to implementation details Mockito sometimes needs users
to provide dummy values for some types, even if they plan to explicitly stub
all the called methods.
package:mockito/src/dummies.dart 156:3         dummyValue
test\user_login_usecase_test.mocks.dart 83:17  MockAuthRepository.loginWithEmailPassword
test\user_login_usecase_test.dart 28:29
